# Nonzero charges medium

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, charge, maxwell-equations

In Maxwell equations, always it is considered that there is no free charge in the medium ($\rho=0$ whatever the medium: conductor, dielectric, ...).

1) In atoms, each electron is a (negative) charge carrier, so what does "free charge" exactly mean ?

2) In which case we can have a medium (or Matter) with nonzero charges ($\rho\neq0$) ? Any example(s) ?

Comment: Assuming $\rho=0$ means that the material is neutral, not that there are no free charges. There are obviously free charges in a conductor.

Comment: So what is your definition for "free charges" ?

Comment: @RobJeffries That's a bit moot, though, since the equivalent treatment of magnetic materials assumes that there are no free currents, and those do occur in conductors.

Comment: To use Maxwell's equations in a conductor you would normally set $\rho=0$. . But J can of course be non-zero because there are free charges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is *not* always assumed that there are no free charges. It depends on the particular problem that one wants to study. When one wants to study free space propagation of light, for instance, then yes, we would assume that there are no free charges. The presence of free charges would mean that the light can interact with these charges and that would complicate things.

Now consider a piece of glass. It is made up of atoms each consisting of a charged nucleus surrounded by charged electrons. Yes, but these charges neutralize each other, so that on the scale of the wavelength of visible light propagating through this piece of glass, these charges would not have any effect. Therefore we say that a piece of glass does not have any *free charges*.

Usually when it states that there are no free charges, it also includes currents. So when we say there are no free charges then the medium does not supporting currents. It is not a conductor. Otherwise, the electric field in the light will cause currents in the medium.

An example of a medium with free charges is a plasma. There one has free charges that can interact with electromagnetic waves (depending on its parameters).

Comment: Well, this is about the first question, what about the second ? Any explanation or example for nonzero charges ?

Answer (score 0):

My usual disclaimer: please view this as an **attempt**, at an answer, as I self study and this is the best way to research and learn. If it is incorrect, I will delete it.

Free charges are those excess charges that can shift into electrostatic equilibrium, so you end up with a time independent electric field. 
Free charge density leads us to Gauss's law., the volume integral of it is associated with free charge density inside a charged object.

An alternative, just to be contrary :) definition is as the carriers of electric current, aka free charges, free meaning in this context, as I am sure you know, from the metal lattice/ crystalline structure.